# If a normal subgroup shares elements with a conjugacy class, then it contains it entirely?

Tags: group-theory

One of my group theory review problems seems to follow directly from definitions, but I'm not sure.

The problem is: Let $G$ be a group and $C$ a conjugacy class of $G$.  Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ with the property that $N \bigcap C \neq \emptyset$, then $C \subset N$.

I know that conjugacy classes are disjoint sets that union to the entire group.  If a normal subgroup, which is the union of conjugacy classes, shares some elements with the conjugacy class, then clearly this conjugacy class must be contained within it.  I'm not sure how to construct a formal proof.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, is true. I
f $\;x\in C\;$ , then any element in $\;C\;$ is of the form $\;x^g:=g^{-1}xg\;$, for some $\;g\in G\;$ ,  and if $\;x\in N\lhd G\;$ , then also $\;x^g\in N\;$ .

From here you could also characterize subgroups *that are normal* as those subgroups which are the (disjoint, of course) union of conjugacy classes in the group